# Need to transfer all files in DOS environment

Tags: dos

I have an old PC running with MS-DOS with DX4-S CPU and base memory 640K and 256K cache.
I need to transfer all the files saved on this PC. I cannot use Floppy disks because I need thousands of them. Can I copy the files through the network? Can I use a CD driver? What would you recommend?

Comment: Does it have an Ethernet card?

Comment: Yes, it does have Ethernet card.

Comment: See below or use some mirror software and run a ftp server on the old PC.

Comment: I would recommend you ask this question at [su] instead, because it has absolutely nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 3):

When your MS-DOS PC and the PC where you want to transfer the files to have a serial port you can try the following:

- make a [null modem cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem)
- get a [terminal emulation program for the MS-DOS PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators#MS-DOS) that supports the z-modem transfer protocol
- get a terminal emulation program for the PC (see link above) where you want to transfer to, that supports the z-modem transfer protocol
- start both programs using the same connection settings, for example 57600 baud 8n1. When the PC is slow, decrease the baud rate on both sites
- use the z-modem protocol to transfer multiple files at once
- have a coffee / soda / beer / some sleep, depending on the size of the files that need transfer
- ready!

Comment: Hi Mark. None of the terminal emulation programs work. Can't I use DOSBox or VMware player?

Comment: Hi WhiteHat, from your comment I understand that you have the terminal program up and running on the MS-DOS PC but have an issue with the terminal program on the PC where you want to transfer to. Did you try: Tera Term (http://ttssh2.osdn.jp/) or SyncTERM (http://syncterm.bbsdev.net/) ? Alternatively you can run a VMware / DOSBox and use the same terminal program on the receiving end as on the sending end. Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Using an RS232 cable I connected both PCs (one with MS-DOS and the other with WIN XP), and installed FILE MAVEN on DOS. Nothing happened actually, DOS could not host WIN. I tried both male and female 9pin and 25pin cables.

Comment: Sure you have a cross cable? (from memory: 2 and 3 must be crossed, 4 and 5 must be crossed as well)

Answer (score 1):

MS-DOS 6.22 comes with INTERSVR.EXE and INTERLNK.EXE that allow you to transfer files over a RS-232 or parallel port.

You need a null-modem cable (RS-232) or a laplink cable (parallel port) to connect the two computers.

You run INTERSVR.EXE on your old computer.
You load INTERLNK.EXE in CONFIG.SYS on the second computer. The drives from your old computer will now be mapped to drives on your second computer and you can copy the files using a file manager of your choice.

I assume that the second computer (or a virtual machine on your second computer) will need to run DOS 6.22 or one of the DOS-based Windows versions (3.11, 95, 98, ME) for this to work.

Comment: True, however INTERLNK.EXE does not come with Windows XP and later...

Comment: Thanks. I will try your and Mark's suggestions, and let you know shortly.

Answer (score 0):

If this installation also contains an old version of windows (3.1) and has an ethernet card, you could use that to transfer your files over.

Otherwise you could install a tcp/ip stack driver for msdos but that would be pretty hard to as you will still need a tool to actually transfer the files.

If the system also has cdrom drive you could use a bootable linux cd to transfer the files over.

If all else fails you could simply take out the hard drive and put it in another pc and copy the files like that. You might need to buy an ide to sata adapter if your other pc doesn't have ide connectors on its mainboard.

Answer (score -2):

KERMIT [The Kermit Project](http://www.kermitproject.org/)  provides file transfer over RS232.  Reviewing the website, it looks like Kermit is available on a variety of platforms and operating systems.

For null modem cable, you can configure KERMIT to use software handshake (XON/XOFF) and then you can hot-wire the handshake lines and just use 3 wires: TX, RX, and Signal Ground.

For example:  For D25 connectors on the cable:

- cross over pins 2 to 3 and 3 to 2 in the wires connecting the connectors
- connect pin 7 straight through connecting wire.
- tie pins 4 and 5 together on each connector but do not connect the wire
- tie pins 6, 8, and 20 together on each connector but do not connect the wire

D9 connectors work the same way but have different pin assignments.

Comment: I'm curious why this answer is voted Down. KERMIT is simple software available in binary and `source code` for almost all platforms including legacy DOS and XP. If you vote this answer down, please leave a comment so I can learn why.